# Alternative to unreliability of GCM

Tags: android, gps, google-cloud-messaging, locationmanager, location-client

I am about to develop GPS vehicle tracking system using android device. Basically, android device will be connected to the vehicle's battery and internet will be always on. user can track his vehicle using web based control panel which fires GCM to wakeup device and send location back. 
Now, here are my questions.

1. GCM is unreliable. I dont want to fail getting location in any condition. even if GCM fails to reach device, is any other way except polling request from server after specific time interval ?
2. As there are two ways , LocationManager and LocationClient and LocationClient requires PlayService installed, what if playService automatically updates itself and some of the methods i am using becomes deprecated (like LocationClient is deprecated now and GoogleApiClient is there) , then will my device stop working ?
3. Any other things I need to take care before installing the device ,Because once the device is installed in vehicle I will never ever have chance to repair mistakes as nobody is there to update the app. Is there any way to automatically update the app when update is available ? Also, when app will be updated, will that effect on previous GCM Register Id ?

Thanks.

Comment: You do want to consider the fact GCM is free and compare it to other services. You can take a look at this - [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191681/is-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-reliable). And you want location based push notification, you can check out Parse Push Notification .

Comment: Consider using an alternative push notification gateway, such as https://pushy.me (Full disclosure - I founded Pushy).