# Is Google Cloud Messaging GCM Reliable?

Tags: android, websocket, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an application that will get some data from the server e.g. live feeds. It will be a multicast message. I just want to know if whether GCM is reliable. I don't want the notification to be on time, if the is a delay of about 1 hour then also it is OK for me. Should I try GCM or go for Web Socket. Does any popular android app use GCM? If yes then please do mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither GCM none other similar services like iOS Push notifications are 100% reliable, but those messages are usually really fast and they always work, so it depends on the level of trust you need. I'd personally go for them.

Comment: I don't mind if I miss out 1-2 messages but I need minimum 70% reliability i.e. out of 10 notification the user should atleast get 7 notifications. Will GCM provide this?

Comment: I would really trust it would

Answer (score 1):

I have used GCM before, and in  my experience it is very reliable.
If at all i faced any issues, they were in upstream messages (i.e from the device to the server).
I would say that you will get much better performance than 70% delivery with a one hour delay.
Go for it! :-)